# sqoop job fails when trying to read table argument

Tags: java, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import some data into a hive table but my sqoop job is failing

```
sqoop import -libjars '/var/lib/sqoop/DB2JccConfiguration.properties' 
--connect 'jdbc:db2://localhost/test;' --username 'name' 
--password-file 'pword' --num-mappers 16 
--query "SELECT P_NUMBER,AG, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, ST, ZIP FROM wU99.snapshot WHERE ZIP = 15392 AND \$CONDITIONS"
--split-by 'AG'--hive-import --hive-table ag.test 
--target_dir '/user/name/Test'


Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p2036.2124/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist!     
Accumulo imports will fail.Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/05/03 16:21:10 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.8.3
17/05/03 16:21:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
17/05/03 16:21:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: AG--hive-import
17/05/03 16:21:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hive-table
17/05/03 16:21:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: ag.test
17/05/03 16:21:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target_dir
17/05/03 16:21:12 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /user/name/Test
```

I don't know why it is failing when it tries to read the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error log is very clearly:
`Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.3-1.cdh5.8.3.p2036.2124/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist!     
Accumulo imports will fail.Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.`

Comment: @mikeL near `AG--hive-import` there should be space after `AG`

Comment: @TuyenNguyen this is just a warning. It has nothing to do with import command failure.

Answer (score 0):

1. There should be space between `'AG'` and `--hive-import`
2. It should be `--target-dir` instead of `--target_dir`

Answer (score 0):

`sqoop import -libjars '/var/lib/sqoop/DB2JccConfiguration.properties' 
--connect 'jdbc:db2://localhost/test;' --username 'name' 
--password-file 'pword' --num-mappers 16 
--query "SELECT P_NUMBER,AG, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, ST, ZIP FROM wU99.snapshot WHERE ZIP = 15392 AND \$CONDITIONS"
--split-by 'AG'  --hive-database 'your_database_name' --hive-import

--target-dir '/user/name/Test'`