# Maven compiler plugin specification

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

If my JDK version is 1.8 and I suppose my project will be running on JDK 1.8. Do I still need to specify this maven property in my pom file?

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

I thought if I am using Jdk 1.8 and I want my project to be compatible with JDK 1.7, then I need this specification. Is that true?

Comment: You're right. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770416/sqoop-job-fails-when-trying-to-read-table-argument#comment74583375_43770416)

Comment: Could you re-paste the link? The current one seems wrong.

Comment: sorry about my mistake. Here is the [link on maven page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always specify these properties, otherwise Maven will default them to `1.5`.

Comment: If that's the case, I would do that.